# Vue 3 CDN : can't include third party component library also from a CDN

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vite, cdn, rollupjs

I published a Vue 3 components library (using Vite), which works fine when imported as a package in a Vue application. However some conflicts appear when both Vue and the library are included via CDN.

This is the Vite config of the components library:

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import { resolve } from "path";
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";
import removeAttr from 'remove-attr';

const prod = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue(),
    removeAttr({
      extensions: [ 'vue' ],
      attributes: prod ?  [ 'data-cy' ] : [],  
  })
  ],
  build: {
    lib: {
      // src/indext.ts is where we have exported the component(s)
      entry: resolve(__dirname, "src/index.js"),
      name: "VueDataUi",
      // the name of the output files when the build is run
      fileName: "vue-data-ui",
      formats: ['es']
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      // make sure to externalize deps that shouldn't be bundled
      // into your library
      external: ["vue"],
      output: {
        // Provide global variables to use in the UMD build
        // for externalized deps
        globals: {
          vue: "Vue",
        },
      },
    },
    types: [
      {
        declarationDir: "dist/types",
        root: resolve(__dirname, "types"),
        entry: "vue-data-ui.d.ts",
      },
    ],
  },
});
```

The `package.json` config related to the build:

```
{
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "main": "./dist/vue-data-ui.umd.cjs",
  "module": "./dist/vue-data-ui.js",
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "import": "./dist/vue-data-ui.js",
      "export": "./dist/vue-data-ui.umd.cjs"
    },
    "./style.css": "./dist/style.css"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "clean": "node cleanup.cjs",
    "build": "npm run clean && vite build --mode production && node copy-types.cjs",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "test": "vitest",
    "test:e2e": "npx cypress open"
  }
}
```

When both included via CDN, like in the following implementation:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Vue 3 CDN Example with Props</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@3.2.19"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <vue-ui-xy :dataset="myDataset"></vue-ui-xy>
  </div>

  <script type="module">
    const { createApp, ref } = Vue

    const { VueUiXy } = await import('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-data-ui@1.9.4/+esm');

    createApp({
      data() {
        return {
          myDataset: [
            {
              name: "Series 1",
              series: [-55, -34, -21, -13, -8, -5, -3, -2, -1, -1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55],
              type: "line",
              color: "rgb(95,139,238)",
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      components: {
        'vue-ui-xy': VueUiXy
      },
      setup() {
        const message = ref('Hello vue!')
        return {
          message
        }
      }
    }).mount('#app')
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The following warning appear in the console:

```
vue.global.js:7963 [Vue warn]: Invalid VNode type: Symbol(v-cmt) (symbol) 
  at <VueUiXy dataset= [{…}] > 
  at <App>
```

Along with this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'nextSibling')
    at nextSibling (vue.global.js:9029:33)
    at te (vue.global.js:6241:18)
    at g (vue.global.js:5080:24)
    at M (vue.global.js:5415:15)
    at R (vue.global.js:5323:15)
    at $ (vue.global.js:5192:15)
    at g (vue.global.js:5109:23)
    at ve.fn (vue.global.js:5716:19)
    at ve.run (vue.global.js:568:31)
    at ks (vue.global.js:8080:38)
```

Which seems to indicate that multiple instances of Vue are running. However, the library build is considering Vue as an external dep, as set in `vite.config` in `build.rollupOptions.external`, which is recommended by the Vue docs.

I would prefer to have a single version of the package that works in all cases (regular package usage, and CDN), are there any tweaks to the build step that can be applied, or is this directly solvable by CDN users with a different setup ?

Comment: Seems you're including vue twice in your component library. This leads to conflicts as both instances of vue are trying to control the same DOM elements.

Comment: Any progress on this issue? Otherwise I'll add a bounty.